# Magento 1.9 - Significance of underscore in SCSS file names?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, rwd, scss

I have two questions (sorry if these seem insignificant I just like knowing the reasoning for things):

1. Why do some of the SCSS files in the new rwd theme have an underscore?
2. In the `styles.scss` file there are two imports, `@import "framework"` & `@import "core"` but the only files that have this name are `_framework.scss` and `_core.scss` - how does this import work when the file name is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just means they are partials, the underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and that it should not be generated into a CSS file but only used with the `@import` directive.

The leading underscore is ignored when you include the files using `@import` so doing `@import "partial"` and `@import "_partial"` generates the same output.

You can read more about it on the [Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/guide).